# XML processing in distributed system

Tags: xml, hadoop

I'm working on Big data from last couple of months.

1

I'm curious to know how XML processing works in multi nodes network. Lets say I have one xml and that's having repetitive tags and in every those tags there are more similar tags.

To process XML, Whole XML needs to be in memory first. So, the moment I submit my hadoop mapreduce task to process 100 GB of XML in the cluster (Lets say 5 node cluster) to process, then how loading of XML in different nodes happens ?

In case of flat files, I can imagine that keep reading the records( one by one) from HDFS and distributing among nodes. But not able to understand in XML. How hadoops know, on what basis of tags splits or distribution needs to happen ?

```
<employees>
    <employee id="be129">
        <firstname>Jane</firstname>
        <lastname>Doe</lastname>
        <title>Engineer</title>
        <division>Materials</division>
        <building>327</building>
        <room>19</room>
        <supervisor>be131</supervisor>
    </employee>
    <employee id="be130">
        <firstname>William</firstname>
        <lastname>Defoe</lastname>
        <title>Accountant</title>
        <division>Accts Payable</division>
        <building>326</building>
        <room>14a</room>
    </employee>
    <employee id="be131">
        <firstname>Jack</firstname>
        <lastname>Dee</lastname>
        <title>Engineering Manager</title>
        <division>Materials</division>
        <building>327</building>
        <room>21</room>
    </employee>
    <employee id="be132">
        <firstname>Sandra</firstname>
        <lastname>Rogers</lastname>
        <title>Engineering</title>
        <division>Materials</division>
        <building>327</building>
        <room>22</room>
    </employee>
    <employee id="be133">
        <firstname>Steve</firstname>
        <lastname>Casey</lastname>
        <title>Engineering</title>
        <division>Materials</division>
        <building>327</building>
        <room>24</room>
    </employee>
    <employee id="be135">
        <firstname>Michelle</firstname>
        <lastname>Michaels</lastname>
        <title>COO</title>
        <division>Management</division>
        <building>216</building>
        <room>264</room>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Lets consider above XML as an example, and imagine there are 10 million of `employee` tags, Then how hadoop mapper splitting mechanism works to distribute xml among 5 nodes and process and coordinate upon distributed XML to process ?

I hope my question is clear to all.

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all, don't use MapReduce. At least, not default options because it only reads line delimited files, not XML formatting

If you want to process xml in parallel, opt for something like `spark-xml` or pre-process the XML documents before they even enter HDFS into a more Hadoop friendly format, for example, using something like Apache Nifi XML/XPath processors

Comment: so you mean distributed xml processing not possible in hadoop until it transformed into flat records ?

Comment: I never said impossible. Its just unnecessarily difficult

Comment: But even its not recomended, then whats's a hadoop mechanism to distribute XML ?

Comment: Its HDFS storage

Comment: Okay. Sorry, what's the question? Spark is a Hadoop compatible mechanism, and works much faster than mapreduce

Comment: There's also Hive xml serdes https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe

Answer (score 0):

The XML parsing pretty well has to be a sequential process, but it doesn't have to build the whole document in memory.

Everything that happens after parsing can be distributed and parallel.

You could do the initial processing of the XML using a SAX parser or using XSLT 3.0 streaming to split it up into smaller chunks, and then send the smaller chunks to multiple parallel processes. I don't know if any frameworks like NiFi will do this for you, or if you have to code it yourself "by hand".

Comment: So you mean to say keep reading the XML bytes or record wise until it becomes the smallest or usable tag and then process further...that’s what you meant ...?

Comment: That's not how I would describe the process, no. Are you familiar with how a SAX parser works?

Comment: @Michael Kay, I know you are creator of SAX parser :) But how it will help to know the mechanism of distribution of XML across the cluster and process in..? And what can be done if smallest chunk itself is 800 GB  in size ..? :)

Comment: @Maria, no, I'm not the creator of any SAX parser. I've done a bit of maintenance work on one or two SAX parsers, but my main contributions have been at the next level up the stack: XPath, XSLT, and XQuery. As to the main question: sorry, but StackOverflow isn't really designed for wide-ranging discussions about choices of technology and application architecture. Try a mailing list such as xml-dev or xsl-list.

Comment: @MichaelKay, But My question is still unanswered, How split mechanism works in Hadoop without mentioning any specific tag ?